# Java- How to modify existing object with new value available in array list?

Tags: java

I have one value object which is set with 10 rows after retrieved values from DB.

I want to update one of the value in all existing 10 rows(objects) with new values.

New values available in List. How to set these values ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as given

```
    for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++) 
{ 
Object object = arrayList.get(i); 
object.setField(newValue); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Object obj : ObjectList)
{
  obj.setValue(currentValue);
}
```

Comment: My List is of type String.

Comment: for eg. I have Student object and have List<String>. I want to update available 10 Student objects one of the value with values available in list of type String.

Comment: you can add some explanation?

Comment: for(Student student:studentList)
{
student.setSchoolName("St peter's school")
}